# make webservice call outside main thread from android

Tags: c#, android, multithreading, web-services

In my code there is a webservice call where webmethod is to simply display astring. I am running the webservice as localhost, but its not working.Ithink the problem is calling webservice from the main thread itself.please can anyone help to call it from a different thread

SoapTestActivity.java

```
package com.sample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.ksoap2.*;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.*;



public class SoapTestActivity extends Activity {
    TextView result;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);

        final String NAMESPACE = "http://sample.com/";
        final String METHOD_NAME = "SayHello";    
        final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://sample.com/SayHello";
        final String URL = "http://192.168.1.104/HelloAndroid/Service1.asmx";

        try {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);            
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
            String resultValue = response.toString();

            result.setText(resultValue);           
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            result.setText(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Service1.asmx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace HelloAndroid 
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://sample.com/")]   
    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    { [WebMethod] 
        public string SayHello() {
        return "Hello, Android from .NET";
    } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html, Check it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Answer (score 2):

You are not advised to make a network call in the main thread of your application,
For this you need to use an Async-task.
[refer this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

sample AsyncTask class

```
private class NetworkTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

     final String NAMESPACE = "http://sample.com/";
        final String METHOD_NAME = "SayHello";    
        final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://sample.com/SayHello";
        final String URL = "http://192.168.1.104/HelloAndroid/Service1.asmx";
        String resultValue ="";
     protected Void doInBackground(Void... urls) {

         try {
             SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);            
             SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
             envelope.dotNet = true;
             envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

             HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
             androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
             SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
              resultValue = response.toString();


         }
         catch (Exception e) {
             resultValue = e.getMessage();
         }
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         result.setText(resultValue);   
     }


 }
```

Invoke this asynctask in onCreate as-

```
new NetworkTask().excecute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an aync-task for this follow the blow code

```
class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>
{
protected void doInBackground(Void...params)
{
final String NAMESPACE = "http://sample.com/";
        final String METHOD_NAME = "SayHello";    
        final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://sample.com/SayHello";
        final String URL = "http://192.168.1.104/HelloAndroid/Service1.asmx";

        try {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);            
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
            String resultValue = response.toString();


        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            result.setText(e.getMessage());
        }
return resultValue;
}
protected void onPostExcecute(String result)
{
super.onPostExecute(result);
result.setText(result);   
}
}
```

now call this Async task by creating an object in MainActivity like `myasyncTask object =new myAsyncTask();`
and now execute it like `object.execute();`

Comment: You should never manipulate Views or UI related items in a background thread or `doInBackground()`. You should pass the results to `onPostExecute()` and to it there. Additionally your AsyncTask definition is wrong. Should be `AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>` unless you change `doInBackground()` to `Void...params` since you're not really using it. (if you do `onPostExecute` you'd add `String` in your last param instead of `Void`)

Comment: just did'nt notice that line